# MYSQL update table rows using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have two tables, 1st table 'score_all' is base table which having score for all group of people and another table 'score_groupA' having score of a group.

```
UPDATE score_groupA A, score_all B 
set A.score = B.score 
WHERE A.peo_id = B.peo_id 
 and A.score <> B.score
```

Above SQL returning 0 updated rows but in table I can see more than hundreds records having different scores and update should happen using above SQL statement.

One thing I noticed that column 'score' of table 'score_all' is defined as float and column 'score' of table 'score_groupA' defined as tinyint. But both table having integer as score value.

For example, below SQL showing many rows having different scores

```
select A.peo_id , B.peo_id, A.score , B.score 
From score_groupA  A, score_all B  
WHERE A.peo_id = B.peo_id
```

but adding the clause '**A.score <> B.score**' returning the 0 records. May be different column type of both table is causing the issue ?

I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: The comparison between a float and tinyint should not be causing the problem.  However, perhaps the float value doesn't fit in the tinyint, which would cause problems.  Are you checking for errors in the `update`?

Comment: try to cast float value to tinyint datatype explicitly.

Comment: Max possible score range between 1-99 and both table having only integer value as score

Comment: @GordonLinoff Update SQL statement is executing without any issue and showing affected rows as 0